# hierarchical data, how to loop all level and insert additional data into each node

Tags: javascript, json, loops, hierarchy, hierarchical-data

I have hierarchical data in Javascript looks like below and I try to find the way add `jsonStringify` in each `comments` node, how to do it?

```
var o = {
  "comments": {
    "count": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "text": "..",

        "comments": {
          "count": 1,
          "data": [
            {
              "text": "..",

              "comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "data": [],
                // "jsonStringify":
              }
            },
          ],
          // "jsonStringify":
        }
      },

      {
        "text": "..",

        "comments": {
          "count": 0,
          "data": [],
          // "jsonStringify":
        }
      },     
    ],
    // "jsonStringify":
  }
};
```

add `jsonStringfy`
this only work with knowing how many level

```
var jsonStringify = JSON.stringify(o.comments);
o.comments.jsonStringify = jsonStringify;

for (var i = 0; i < o.comments.data.length; i++) {
  var jsonStringify = JSON.stringify(o.comments.data[i].comments);
  o.comments.data[i].comments.jsonStringify = jsonStringify;
}
```

for example above data have 2 branch, and the deepest level is 3 (
"comments" > "comments" > "comments",
"comments" >"comments"),
I want to find each "comments" get the value like below `1` and apply to `JSON.stringify` function get result then modified the same node insert the result become `2`

```
1
"comments": {
  "count": 0,
  "data": []
}
2
"comments": {
  "count": 0,
  "data": [],
  "jsonStringify": "{\"count\":0,\"data\":[]}"
}
```

**I try to find the way if the data unknown how many level**

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking here.

Comment: Do you want to find each node named 'comments' and then apply the `jsonStringify()` function to its value?  And if so, what do you want to the result of the stringifying?

Comment: @JohnHascall Thanks for reply, yes I want to find each node "comments" and apply `JSON.stringify()` to its value, then append the result to the same "comments" node

Comment: still don't get it, maybe it's the wording you use.  can you give an example of input and output? Do you want to serialize sth. or is this your approach to achieve the goal? What do you want to end with? an Object or a String?

Comment: @Thomas please see my update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was answered before original question were modified with the remark to the different count numbers.
Still waiting for author to elaborate about it.

Source code:

```
var o = {
  "comments": {
    "count": 2,
    "data": [
      {
        "text": "..",
        "comments": {
          "count": 1,
          "data": [
            {
              "text": "..",

              "comments": {
                "count": 0,
                "data": [],
              }
            },
          ]
        }
      },
      {
        "text": "..",
        "comments": {
          "count": 0,
          "data": []
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

function jsonStringify(array){
  for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++){
    var ar = array[i];
    ar.comments.jsonStringify = JSON.stringify(ar.comments);
    ar.comments.data = jsonStringify(ar.comments.data);
    array[i] = ar;
  }
  return array;
}

var result = jsonStringify([o]);

console.log( JSON.stringify(result,null,'\t') );
```

result:

```
[
    {
        "comments": {
            "count": 2,
            "data": [
                {
                    "text": "..",
                    "comments": {
                        "count": 1,
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "text": "..",
                                "comments": {
                                    "count": 0,
                                    "data": [],
                                    "jsonStringify": "{\"count\":0,\"data\":[]}"
                                }
                            }
                        ],
                        "jsonStringify": "{\"count\":1,\"data\":[{\"text\":\"..\",\"comments\":{\"count\":0,\"data\":[]}}]}"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "text": "..",
                    "comments": {
                        "count": 0,
                        "data": [],
                        "jsonStringify": "{\"count\":0,\"data\":[]}"
                    }
                }
            ],
            "jsonStringify": "{\"count\":2,\"data\":[{\"text\":\"..\",\"comments\":{\"count\":1,\"data\":[{\"text\":\"..\",\"comments\":{\"count\":0,\"data\":[]}}]}},{\"text\":\"..\",\"comments\":{\"count\":0,\"data\":[]}}]}"
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this seems only work with knowing how many level comments

Comment: sorry, I didn't quite get it then. How do you need to have the mechanics working then?

Comment: can you show the final JSON that you want to have with already calculated `jsonStringify` fields please?

Comment: the result in your answer is the data format what I I want , but my question is make a function work with don't have to know how many level within the hierarchical data.

Comment: oh my god so sorry waste ur time I only read you code but not test, and miss the function calling inside